# Translating in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, language, translation

Sometimes Google will offer to translate a page for me but it seems random when it offers. Is there a way I can force this feature to happen on any page (where I specify the language).

:)

Answer (score 5):

Get the translate extention

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes even if it doesn't offer, you can right-click and select "Translate to English".