# How to force Chrome to translate

Tags: google-chrome, translation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Chromium to always automatically translate all languages](https://superuser.com/questions/206019/set-chromium-to-always-automatically-translate-all-languages)

It seems Google Chrome only translates pages when it auto-discovers they are in another language, and they make a very poor job at doing that. Is there a way to force Chrome to translate a page from German to English when Chrome believes it's in English? (The first 5 words are in English, everything else is in German).

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried rightclick->translate to english?

Comment: Also dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/136174/translating-in-google-chrome both offer the same solution

Comment: @jnk: yes, that option is dissabled